# PowerBuilder 12.6 INI Password Encryption

Tags: encryption, ini, powerbuilder

I need to Encrypt/Decrypt PowerBuilder INI File Password.
Currently Passwords are stored in plain text.(*Only Password needs to be encrypted*)

**Example:**
UserId="TEST"
DBPassword="P@ssw0rd"

Wanted to know what are the options as per latest Security Standards.
*Don't need public private key management strategies.*

Application is on PB12.6

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyber_security_standards

Answer (score 2):

I have two free examples of encryption in PowerBuilder:

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_bcrypt.html

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_cryptoapi.html

BCrypt is a newer crypto library Microsoft introduced in Windows Vista. You should be able to find something suitable using one of these examples.